# Running doctests through iPython and pseudo-consoles

Tags: python, django, ipython

I've got a fairly basic doctestable file:

```
class Foo():
    """
    >>> 3+2
    5
    """

if __name__ in ("__main__", "__console__"):
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

which works as expected when run directly through python.

However, in iPython, I get

```
1 items had no tests:
    __main__
0 tests in 1 items.
0 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Since this is part of a Django project and will need access to all of the appropriate variables and such that manage.py sets up, I can also run it through a modified command, which uses code.InteractiveConsole, one result of which is `__name__` gets set to '`__console__`'.

With the code above, I get the same result as with iPython.  I tried changing the last line to this:

```
 this = __import__(__name__)
 doctest.testmod(this, verbose=True)
```

and I get an ImportError on `__console__`, which makes sense, I guess.  This has no effect on either python or ipython.

So, I'd like to be able to run doctests successfully through all three of these methods, especially the InteractiveConsole one, since I expect to be needing Django pony magic fairly soon.

Just for clarification, this is what I'm expecting:

```
Trying:
    3+2
Expecting:
    5
ok
1 items had no tests:
    __main__
1 items passed all tests:
   1 tests in __main__.Foo
1 tests in 2 items.
1 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Comment: I suppose I should note that `doctest.run_docstring_examples(Foo, {}, verbose=True)` works (well, from minor testing), but I'd rather not do that for each class, even in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
$ ipython
...
In [1]: %run file.py

Trying:
    3+2
Expecting:
    5
ok
1 items had no tests:
    __main__
1 items passed all tests:
   1 tests in __main__.Foo
1 tests in 2 items.
1 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.

In [2]:
```

I have no idea why `ipython file.py` does not work. But the above is at least a workaround.

**EDIT:**

I found the reason why it does not work. It is quite simple:

- If you do not specify the module to test in `doctest.testmod()`, it assumes that you want to test the `__main__` module.
- When IPython executes the file passed to it on the command line, the `__main__` module is IPython's `__main__`, not your module. So doctest tries to execute doctests in IPython's entry script.

The following works, but feels a bit weird:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    import the_current_module
    doctest.testmod(the_current_module)
```

So basically the module imports itself (that's the "feels a bit weird" part). But it works. Something I do not like abt. this approach is that every module needs to include its own name in the source.

**EDIT 2:**

The following script, `ipython_doctest`, makes ipython behave the way you want:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

echo "__IP.magic_run(\"$1\")" > __ipython_run.py
ipython __ipython_run.py
```

The script creates a python script that will execute `%run argname` in IPython.

Example:

```
$ ./ipython_doctest file.py
Trying:
    3+2
Expecting:
    5
ok
1 items had no tests:
    __main__
1 items passed all tests:
   1 tests in __main__.Foo
1 tests in 2 items.
1 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
Python 2.5 (r25:51908, Mar  7 2008, 03:27:42) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.9.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object'. ?object also works, ?? prints more.

In [1]:
```

Comment: Solution in first edit marked as accepted.  The second would be great, but it's iPython-specific, and using iPython was just one of the ways I could get the symptoms to exhibit themselves.  I agree that it feels a bit "eh", but it's simple and gets the job done.

Comment: Also, creating a temporary file like you do in edit #2 is a bit ugly.  The following shell function does the same thing: `function ipython_doctest () ipython -c "__IP.magic_run(\"$1\")"`

Comment: ..although that would require all the developers to include that in their shell, rather than providing a distributable file.  Alright, I'm done.

Answer (score 8):

The root problem is that `ipython` plays weird tricks with `__main__` (through its own `FakeModule` module) so that, by the time `doctest` is introspecting that "alleged module" through its `__dict__`, `Foo` is *NOT* there -- so doctest doesn't recurse into it.

Here's one solution:

```
class Foo():
    """
    >>> 3+2
    5
    """

if __name__ in ("__main__", "__console__"):
    import doctest, inspect, sys
    m = sys.modules['__main__']
    m.__test__ = dict((n,v) for (n,v) in globals().items()
                            if inspect.isclass(v))
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

This DOES produce, as requested:

```
$ ipython dot.py 
Trying:
    3+2
Expecting:
    5
ok
1 items had no tests:
    __main__
1 items passed all tests:
   1 tests in __main__.__test__.Foo
1 tests in 2 items.
1 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Feb  6 2009, 19:02:12) 
  [[ snip snip ]]
In [1]:
```

Just setting global `__test__` doesn't work, again because setting it as a global of what you're thinking of as `__main__` does NOT actually place it in the `__dict__` of the actual object that gets recovered by `m = sys.modules['__main__']`, and the latter is exactly the expression `doctest` is using internally (actually it uses `sys.modules.get`, but the extra precaution is not necessary here since we do know that `__main__` exists in `sys.modules`... it's just NOT the object you expect it to be!-).

Also, just setting `m.__test__ = globals()` directly does not work either, for a different reason: `doctest` checks that the values in `__test__` are strings, functions, classes, or modules, and without some selection you cannot guarantee that `globals()` will satisfy that condition (in fact it won't). Here I'm selecting just classes, if you also want functions or whatnot you can use an `or` in the `if` clause in the genexp within the `dict` call.

I don't know exactly how you're running a Django shell that's able to execute your script (as I  believe `python manage.py shell` doesn't accept arguments, you must be doing something else, and I can't guess exactly what!-), but a similar approach should help (whether your Django shell is using ipython, the default when available, or plain Python): appropriately setting `__test__` in the object you obtain as `sys.modules['__main__']` (or `__console__`, if that's what you're then passing on to doctest.testmod, I guess) should work, as it mimics what doctest will then be doing internally to locate your test strings.

And, to conclude, a philosophical reflection on design, architecture, simplicity, transparency, and "black magic"...:

All of this effort is basically what's needed to defeat the "black magic" that ipython (and maybe Django, though it may be simply delegating that part to ipython) is doing on your behalf for your "convenience"... any time at which two frameworks (or more;-) are independently doing each its own brand of black magic, interoperability may suddenly require substantial effort and become anything BUT convenient;-).

I'm not saying that the same convenience could have been provided (by any one or more of ipython, django and/or doctests) *without* black magic, introspection, fake modules, and so on; the designers and maintainers of each of those frameworks are superb engineers, and I expect they've done their homework thoroughly, and are performing only the minimum amount of black magic that's indispensable to deliver the amount of user convenience they decided they needed. Nevertheless, even in such a situation, "black magic" suddenly turns from a dream of convenience to a nightmare of debugging as soon as you want to do something even marginally outside what the framework's author had conceived.

OK, maybe in this case not quite a nightmare, but I do notice that this question has been open a while and even with the lure of the bounty it didn't get many answers yet -- though you now do have two answers to pick from, mine using the `__test__` special feature of doctest, @codeape's using the peculiar `__IP.magic_run` feature of ironpython. I prefer mine because it does not rely on anything internal or undocumented -- `__test__` IS a documented feature of doctest, while `__IP`, with those two looming leading underscores, scream "deep internals, don't touch" to me;-)... if it breaks at the next point release I wouldn't be at all surprised. Still, matter of taste -- that answer may arguably be considered more "convenient".

But, this is exactly my point: convenience may come at an enormous price in terms of giving up simplicity, transparency, and/or avoidance of internal/undocumented/unstable features; so, as a lesson for all of us, the least black magic &c we can get away with (even at the price of giving up an epsilon of convenience here and there), the happier we'll all be in the long run (and the happier we'll make other developers that need to leverage our current efforts in the future).

Comment: +1 For the insightful discussion of 'black magic' in frameworks.

Comment: You make some interesting points. But the fact that your solution requires modification of the modules under test makes me believe that my solution is "better". But then I'm biased. And ``inspect.isclass(v)`` is not enough to get to all doctests. You also need include functions and the module docstring.

Comment: No modifications of the modules under test: rather, addition of explicit `__test__` in the _pseudo_-module that ipython builds and passes off as being the alleged `__main__`. Could as easily be performed in a separate auxiliary module (even the ones ipython automatically imports at startup) just as well as anywhere else, of course.  And, I _did_ say **if you also want functions or whatnot you can use an or** -- so, I'm not sure what your point is, there?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. Do you not need to modify the ``if __name__ == '__main__':`` part of the module source code? Can your approach be used without changing the source code of the module? Sorry, I missed the 'if you also want functions or whatnot' part when I read your answer.

Comment: BTW, 'Python in a nutshell' is the one book I always keep on my desk. The best book on Python, IMO. You are the person who in effect taught me Python! Nice.

Comment: @codeape, tx for the Nutshell kudos;-).  Wrt the other issue, you can call doctest.testmod from any module, and pass it any module explicitly as its first argument; the point of my answer is making sure that module, whether implicitly or explicitly passed, has a `__test__` which lists all the items to test. At any rate, as the OP already was testing for `"__console__"`, it's clear they don't need to use a module that only supports standard Python -- they're already editing it to support ipython, some kind of Django console, etc etc; so doing that support **right** is a minor issue;-).

Comment: "I don't know exactly how you're running a Django shell that's able to execute your script (as I believe python manage.py shell doesn't accept arguments, you must be doing something else, and I can't guess exactly what!-)" - I've added another project-specific manage.py command that's basically just a hack of `manage.py shell` to allow one argument as a file to be run.  That uses InteractiveConsole, which is why I have to test for `__console__`.

Comment: @Alex: I found a case where your approach will differ from the default doctest in a significant way. Say the module under test has an import ``from somemodule import Bar`` and class Bar has a doctest. Your approach will execute the doctest for Bar. doctest run the "normal" way will not execute Bar's doctest.

Comment: ^ This is a killer, although it's a bit clever for my tastes, anyways (I found it ironic that this solution produces some of the bad behaviors complained about in the latter half :)).  codeape's self-importing method has its own problems, but it's quite clear; I'm plenty good at making unclear code on my own. ;)