# Difference between "None" end "pass" in a try/except statement in terms of calculation time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using and try/except statement in python inside a very long loop. If the exception is raised, it should do nothing.

```
try :
  *Some Code*
except :
  pass
```

If i use this first proposition, the total time of calculation for the loop is about **10 minutes**.

```
try :
  *Some Code*
except :
  None
```

If i use this second propositon, the total time of calculation for the loop is about **2 minutes**.

Why is it so different, and why is the second one faster as, logically for me, *pass* is a better solution than *None* ?

The exact code is :

```
try:
 indexes = peakutils.peak.interpolate(self.list_height, input_1, ind=indexes, width=self.gauss_width)
except:
 None / Pass
```

I made several tests with both propisitons and it's always the same.

How time is calculated :

```
start = default_timer()
im.get_events() #The loop where the try/except statement appears
finish = default_timer()
print('ELAPSED TIME : %s'%(finish - start))
```

Comment: did you made the tests in the same conditions ? how many times did you retry them?

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using to benchmark both code snippets?

Comment: What is *Some Code*, how and how often did you time it and is every calculation in *Some Code* static in the sense that computational effort does not change between executions?

Comment: cannot reproduce with a simple loop benchmark. Using `None` yields to slower results, actually...

Comment: *Some Code* must be changing between the first and 2nd snippet or your timing method is off, show both

Comment: Use `timeit`, not a stopwatch...

Comment: I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966750/measure-time-of-a-function-with-arguments-in-python to evaluate the calculation time

Comment: Show the `timeit` code you used

Comment: I used exactly this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1966841/5132566

Comment: @Dedi that isn't your code, show your code in the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two functions:

```
def func_none():
  return None

def func_pass():
  pass
```

They are doing exactly the same thing, the proof using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#module-dis):

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(func_none)
# 0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
# 3 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis(func_pass)
# 0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
# 3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Indeed, here is the definition of [pass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement):

> pass is a null operation — when it is executed, nothing happens. It is
>   useful as a placeholder when a statement is required syntactically,
>   but no code needs to be executed, for example:

**Conclusion**: `pass` statement is as fast as `None`*in theory*.

**Edit**: why it *may* be a slower time using `None` instead of `return None` (like in OP example).

Given two functions:

```
def func_none():
  try:
    1/0
  except:
    None

def func_pass():
  try:
    1/0
  except:
    pass
```

The difference using dis:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(func_none)
# Skip to expect part

  18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
  21 POP_TOP             
  22 JUMP_FORWARD             1 (to 26)
  25 END_FINALLY         
  26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
  29 RETURN_VALUE  

dis.dis(func_pass)

# Skip to expect part

  18 JUMP_FORWARD             1 (to 22)
  21 END_FINALLY         
  22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
  25 RETURN_VALUE
```

So it is clear that using `None` instead of `pass` will add two extra operation `LOAD_CONST` and `POP_TOP`. It shouldnt add 8 minutes though, so I'm sure this isn't the real reason.

Comment: This isn't exactly the same thing as the OP's code.  A function implicitly returns `None` if there is no return statement, and `pass` does not compile to any code, which is why the two functions have the same disassembly on CPython.  Adding `None` as a separate statement will add some code to load the constant, though, so it is actually slower than `pass`.

Comment: Thanks for the aswer. Even if it does not explain the reason, i am assured that it _should_ be identical.

Comment: You could simply have changed the code of the `func_none()` to just `None` instead of `return None`, and you would have seen the same difference.  This is not specific to try/except;  it'st just how expression statements are compiled in CPython.

Comment: @Dedi, you are right, I edited my answer to add extra informations. It still does not explain the issue though.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, thanks for the comment, you are totally right, I edited the question to try to catch the difference in the second part. Do you think it is somewhat useful?

Comment: @Max Chrétien, thanks for this. As you can guess, it is a purely theorical question and does not really change the final code.

Comment: @Dedi, yes I understand. this is a total legitimate question and I'm sorry I can't explain the reason of such a big gap between your 2 pieces of code.