# Using timeit with args,kwargs

Tags: python

If I have a function like this:

```
def print_args(wait=0.4, *args, **kwargs):
    print (f"Sleep: {wait}s")
    time.sleep(wait)
    print (f"Args: {args}")
    print (f"Kwargs: {kwargs}")

>>> print_args(0.2, 2, k='a')
Sleep: 0.2s
Args: (2,)
Kwargs: {'k': 'a'}
```

How would I put the function `print_args` into `timeit`?

This works:

```
>>> timeit(print_args, number=4)
```

But how to do:

```
>>> timeit(print_args(0.2, 2, k='a', number=4)
```

Additionally, is there a generic way to do this something like:

```
timeit(func(*args, **kwargs), number)
```

(And not just re-writing the above `print_args` function but having something more generic for this pattern.

**UPDATE**: Note I'm not interested in writing a timer as a decorator in the function, or running something from the command line. I am literally asking if it's possible to do something like this:

```
timeit(func(*args, **kwargs), number)
```

If for whatever reason [the mentioned duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966750/measure-time-of-a-function-with-arguments-in-python) addresses this directly, please tell me which answer does so. The answers I've seen either suggest adding a timer or to use "IPython's `%timeit` command". This is not what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measure time of a function with arguments in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966750/measure-time-of-a-function-with-arguments-in-python)

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb please see my question update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the result of `func(*args, **kwargs)` is the callable you want to time, `timeit(func(*args, **kwargs), number)` is obviously not going to do what you want. Wrap the call in a lambda or function instead:

```
timeit(lambda: func(*args, **kwargs), number)
```