# How to calculate the WPM when using a stopwatch to time words?

Tags: python, math, wpm

I am doing a typing speed test, however, instead of waiting to 60 seconds, I am using a specific amount of words and a stopwatch to time it.

My recent calculation is:

```
WPM = number_of_words / (time / 60)
```

However, if I spend 13 seconds typing 8 words, then my WPM is around 37. I tested this line of code on a real calculator, and it shows that this line is working, which means my formula is incorrect. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming question so far and it's unclear why the formula should be incorrect.

Comment: Please add such an amount of your code that we can see what is wrong. With this little information we will not get beyond guessing and chatter.

Comment: BTW: Isn't this https://stackoverflow.com/q/32621299/2932052 closely related to your actual goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should run correctly, you need to check if the time is being timed in miliseconds, as that is a common practice. Then you shouldn't divide by 60. Other than that, I think it should work as intended, hope it helps.

Comment: Should be in comments

Comment: @Sujay Well, but remember that commenting on posts of others requires 50+ rep.

Comment: Please show some more of the solution you are talking about as to take this to the level of a real answer!