# Will DNSpython use Cache?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dnspython

I'm using DNSPython library to get DNS resolution time in my script. I've a query on the caching part, that whether this library uses Cache on its own. My requirement is to check how much it takes to resolve DNS from a endpoint.

Here's the part of script I'm using to get resolution time now,

```py
resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver.timeout = 1
resolver.lifetime = 1
return float("{0:.3f}".format(dns.resolver.query(url).response.time*1000))
```

If DNSPython uses caching, suggest me a way to flush it. Also suggest me some other idea if available, to get DNS resolution time without caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If DNSPython uses caching, suggest me a way to flush it. Also suggest
>   me some other idea if available, to get DNS resolution time without
>   caching.

```py
dns.resolver.Cache.flush()
```

See the [source here](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.16.0/dns.resolver-pysrc.html#Cache.flush) and the [documentation here](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.16.0/).

Most (virtually all?) operating systems have command line utilities that drop DNS cache. Use in conjunction with [time](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time) for performance benchmarking. Perhaps also consider a [timing decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622943/timeit-versus-timing-decorator) in your python code for benchmarking.