# How can I tell when a Flask request has begin, even before full request has been received?

Tags: python, flask, time, upload

I want to time how long it takes to upload a file to a Flask app.  I am trying to use something like this to know when the upload starts:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.start = time.time()
```

However, `before_request` fires only after the full request (file) has been uploaded, so at most, all I can measure how long it takes to process the uploaded file.

Is there another signal/decorator I can use to determine when a Request has been initiated, even before the full request is available? (ie when a user starts to upload a file, but before it begins?)

Comment: Yes, you can stack decorators. Most elegant way is to write your own timer decorator. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27737385/12060936

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I am correct, just guessing here.

Flask is not the web server itself, it only servers as a CGI application. My guess is the web server (e.g. the dev server you use or an Apache HTTP server) is able to know whether a request has arrived, and it will receive the file. When it is completed, it will dispatch the request to Flask.

Comment: I think you're likely right @DrizzleX .  I can't find anything in Flask docs to trigger _before_ a request is dispatched, only `before_request` to fire after dispatching and before handling (to be clear, there is a trigger before dispatching when using Blueprints, but even then, then Flask app has the full request in hand).