# Track CPU and memory usage of a python function

Tags: python, testing, psutil

I have a function written in Python. I want to get the average (or peak) cpu and memory usage while the function is running.

However, I do not want to do those measurements from inside the function - I do not want to change the function itself.

I want to call the function and make the measurements while the function is running.

How should I address this?

I have looked into `psutil`, but still not sure how to do it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: you could create function which get values from `psutil`, runs your original function, and get again  `psutil`. And they you can repalce functions. You could even create `decorator` for this. As I know there was module which use decorator to run `time` before and after executing function. See [timeit versus timing decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622943/timeit-versus-timing-decorator) to see how to create decoreator for measurements.

Comment: if you want to measure it all time while function is running then you may have to run `psutil` in separated thread - and run loop which get values every few (milli)seconds.