# What is faster? Two list comprehensions or one and a list.copy()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime, list-comprehension

Which of the following is faster?

```
a = ['' for _ in range(len(x))]
b = ['' for _ in range(len(x))]
```

or

```
a = ['' for _ in range(len(x))]
b = a.copy()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hard to say considering both codes will not run due to syntax problems.

Comment: An important thing as well is that those 2 snippets do 2 **very** different things, which makes comparing them pointless.

Comment: They do very different things, the first one creates a lot of empty lists twice, the second one does only creates them once and then copy a reference to them, if the first one has 2 N empty lists, the second one only has N empty lists, referenced from both a and b.

Comment: the .copy() is preventing the reference problem

Comment: It's not. You are copying references to the same inner lists.

Comment: You can very easily see that by adding anything to one of the empty lists and looking at the other one - added element will be visible inside the other list as well.

Comment: ahh ok didnt think about that, what if i did the same thing but with strings inside my lists?

Comment: Edit the question to show what exactly you have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see for yourself easily with a timing decorator:

```
from functools import wraps
from time import time

def timing(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kw):
        ts = time()
        result = f(*args, **kw)
        te = time()
        print(f'func:{f.__name__} args:[{args}, {kw}] took: {te-ts} sec')
        return result
    return wrap

x = 10000000
@timing
def a(x):
    a = ['' for _ in range(x)]
    b = [i for i in a]
@timing
def b(x):
    a = ['' for _ in range(x)]
    b = a.copy()

a(x)
b(x)
```

Comment: Thats pretty cool! could you explain how this works?

Comment: Sure, it's just a decorator that wraps the decorated function, storing a time before and after function call. It's taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27737385/9296093), updated to Python 3. The decorators are sort of wrapper functions that can do some stuff to the function they are decorating.

Comment: does that mean that I can use the timing decorator and function to measure the time of a function while it still working normal?

Comment: Yes, any function decorated with this will do its job as normal, but it will also print the message each time it finishes.

Comment: maybe you could take a look at this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/74151564/15018486